# Create new webform on button click in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have an asp.net website in Visual Studio using C#. I have created a master page, and I want users to be able to dynamically create new webforms using that master page by clicking a button. For example, a user fills out a field with a desired page name and clicks a "Submit" button. A new webform named "pagename.aspx" using the master page will be created.

Any idea how this can be accomplished? Thank you!